# Пуш в массив со сдвигом вправо

Tags: javascript

Задумка такова, что у меня должен быть массив объектов с длинной 4:

```
const array = [{}, {}, {}, {}];
```

Хочу, чтобы при пуше в этот массив значение попадало всегда на первую позицию, а уже существующие значения сдвигались вправо. То есть, первое значение встало на второе место, второе - на третье и так далее. Думал, что функция `splice()` мне в этом поможет, но это не то, что мне нужно. Как мне реализовать задуманное не прибегая к помощи фреймворков?

Comment: Судя по соотношению 3:1, Вы недостаточно подчеркнули требование постоянной длины массива. Или это я неправильно понял?

Comment: @Igor наоборот, вы всё правильно поняли и, видимо, это всё-таки я неправильно составил предложение :) Длина массива должна быть именно 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

```js
const t = [1,2,3,4];
t.unshift(5);
t.pop();
console.log(t);
```

[Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const t = [1,2,3,4];
console.log([5, ...t]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

arr.splice(0, 0, 123);
arr.length = 4;

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Не успел но все же..

```js
    const myArr = [1,2,3,4];
    myArr.unshift(0);
    alert(myArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```js
var a = [23, 45, 12, 67];
a.unshift(34);
console.log(a); // [34, 23, 45, 12, 67]
```